# com.facebook.react.common.javascriptexception uncaught referenceerror: regeneratorruntime is not defined

Tags: react-native

I can run the app on `ios` but when try to run on `android` I get this error! how can I fix it?
I tried `./gradlew clean` but nothing happened! and also my code was running until yesterday. does it have a general solution?

```
 Environment:
  OS: macOS High Sierra 10.13
  Node: 8.9.4
  Yarn: 1.5.1
  npm: 6.0.0
  Watchman: 4.9.0
  Xcode: Xcode 9.2 Build version 9C40b
  Android Studio: 3.1 AI-173.4720617

Packages: (wanted => installed)
  react: 16.0.0 => 16.0.0
  react-native: 0.54.2 => 0.54.2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

import babel-polyfill

click the following for reference, this might solve your issue

https://github.com/babel/babel-preset-env/issues/112

```
Can you try deleting your android, ios and node modules folder and run the following

1.> npm install // to get dependecies loaded
2.> react-native upgrade // to create ios and android folder
3.> react-native link // to link the libraries
4.> react-native run-android
```

Answer (score -3):

1. Close metro bundler
2. Go to the root of your project
3. Run `npm start`